# Ubuntu autocompletion shortcut not worked

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

---

### Intro

Yesterday I treid to Install Linux manjaro in my laptop, and install it use the same `/home` partition. And because I get some trouble with interface and accidentally deleted all config file in `/home`.

---

### The Problem

When I try to switch again to my Ubuntu, I tried to write `sudo apt upgrade` in konsole (terminal). But when I try to click `tab` button while `sudo apt upg`, it show `sudo apt upgrade-from-grub-legacy`, and I see nothing `sudo apt upgrade` in the shortcut. Can some anyone help me? I think some config in USER directory or whatever get missing. I also tried in tty, but give a same thing.

---

### Spec

```
Ubuntu version: 22.04
Kernel version: 5.18.0-051800-generic x86_64
Deskto Environ: LXQt 0.17.1
```

---

Comment: It's okay, I accidentally fixed it myself

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by reinstalling `bash-completion`, and copy copying file `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`  to `~/.bashrc`